# Qt/Qml Managing dynamic C++ items in a ListView

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I have built a C++/QML app in which I use a QList-based model in a QML ListView. I have adapted it from Qt's example here (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html), so I will use their code for my question.

Say I have adapted their sample code to the following:

```
class MyDataWidget : public QQuickWidget
{

public:
    MyDataWidget(QObject* parent = nullptr)
        : QQuickWidget(parent)
    {
        setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/myDataWidget.qml"));        
    }

    void loadNewData()
    {
        _dataList.clear();
        _dataList.append(new DataObject("Item 1", "red"));
        _dataList.append(new DataObject("Item 2", "green"));
        _dataList.append(new DataObject("Item 3", "blue"));
        _dataList.append(new DataObject("Item 4", "yellow"));

        rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(_dataList));
    }

private:
    QList<QObject*> _dataList;
}
```

I also added a destructor to `DataObject` with a debug message so I could verify that the old objects were being released. But they weren't! So instead of manually going through `_dataList` before the `clear()` call, I instead just manage a list of `std::shared_ptr<QObject*>`, so that the code ended up looking something like:

```
public:
    void loadNewData()
    {
        QList<Object*> modelList;
        _dataList.clear();

        auto temp = std::make_shared<DataObject>("Item 1", "red");
        _dataList.push_back(temp);
        modelList.push_pack(temp.get()); 

        ...

        rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(modelList));
    }

private:
    QList<std::shared_ptr<QObject>> _dataList;
```

Now this kind of worked. I was indeed seeing breakpoints/debug-messages in my DataObject destructors (which I wasn't seeing before) but this lead to a new problem. I would get a crash in the `rootContext->setContextProperty()` in `QListViewPrivate::releaseItem()` (I think that was the name of it), which leads me to believe that it's attempting to release the objects that were already cleared in `_dataList.clear()`. But if that's the case, why was `DataObject`'s destructors ever invoked?

My solution, for now, is to call `rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant{});` before the `_dataList.clear`. Like such:

```
void loadNewData()
{
    QList<Object*> modelList;

    rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant{});
    _dataList.clear();

    ...
```

But this feels like a hack.

What would be a 'better' way to manage these dynamic objects (I actually find this to be one of the most ambiguous aspects of Qt in general)? I could attach them to a parent object that gets reset on each call to `loadNewData` but having an object exist soley for that purpose doesn't seem right either.

Another question is, when I tried to use the `_dataList` object directly like such:

`rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(_dataList));`

And after declaring it as a meta type (hence `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`) I was never able to get that work, the QML never rendered the objects as expected. But maybe that deserves another question altogether.

Comment: first, if you have a `QList` of some pointers, removing items from that list with `list.clear()` or else obviously does not delete the object(s) itself. you have to manage the memory yourself and delete them when `clear()` is called, e.g. with `qDeleteAll(list);` before your clear the list.

Comment: I was unaware of `qDeteleAll(list)`. I will try that. I like one simple call better than having to manage the memory myself with shared pointers (or something else).

Comment: `qDeleteAll(list);` is effectively just a loop to delete all the items in a container, nothing that fancy, but since it's sometimes needed it makes the code clearer: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll-1

Comment: Calling `qDeleteAll(list)` still requires calling `rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant{});` beforehand. Is there any way to clean up the allocated objects without having to temporarily set an empty list?

Comment: I think the problem is more that QList is an unmanaged list, when you modify it via it's methods how is QML supposed to know that the model changed, QList has no data changed signals.. your approach is better used with read only lists. If you need a dynamic list the better approach is to use a proper list model, like [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) and expose that to QML. (I think that is also mentioned in your model data link above)

Comment: I agree with @xander a dynamic data situation can be handled easier and better with a propery list model implementation. However, if you really want to stick to a list of objects, I would recommend exposing it as a property of an object instead of setting the list as data value via `setContextProperty?